# Does most fungus grow better in hot damp conditions, or normal temperature conditions?

Tags: growth, fungus, temperature

I'm trying to figure out whether or not I should add some life compost to top dress an area I'm trying to promote fungal action in that area or not. Does most fungus grow better in compost like conditions, or normal temperature conditions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_life  This is a very simplified list of what is in an average soil (what ever that means), I have seen far longer lists of very ucky soil.  The trick is to wake the fungus up, and all that entails is 50 degrees F to 85 degrees F soil temperature, a bit of moisture and DOM, decomposed organic material.  All the fungi you could want is in your soil already, black thumb.  I am dying to see what happens however.  Most times, more is never better.  I dunno if anyone has tried this experiment. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soil_life

Comment: i have read up on a lot of this stuff already

Comment: Does your information tell you that more is better where fungus is concerned?  Please let us know how your experiment works out.  Thanks!

Comment: if a little is good, a lot is better ;) ;)

Comment: I sure wish, black thumb...unfortunately, more is never better.  You'll see.  We aren't in control of anything. Being able to understand the big picture of most stuff is so humbling.

Comment: I need to get the back to eden done within about a month to get the bumper crop i'm hoping for

Comment: What is 'back to eden' stuff you have to do.  I am dying to either learn something from you or help you to not OVER garden.  This is tough trying to understand other gardeners over this internet.  Sorry.  Bumper crop of what?

Comment: @stormy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rPPUmStKQ4

Comment: @black thumb The answer to your question is, it depends (as usual) mainly.. on the fungus. I am a bit confused thought, are you growing fungus (ie mushrooms) or moss?

Comment: edible fungi primarily

Answer (score 1):

Its not entirely clear what you're asking. If you want to promote mycorrhizal content in the open soil, that'll be there already anyway, and adding good composted materials may increase it, but it won't destroy it. If you mean fruiting fungal bodies such as mushrooms, that's another matter.

Comment: I'm trying to make the mycorrhizal fungi that i'll be walking in populate all of the mulch added to the walkways so that the nutrients can be ready to spread to the plants that want different nutrients so the fungi can receive the gift of plant sugars.

Comment: walkways? hard surface walkways, like concrete, or just soil? seems a terrible waste of good compost, if that's what you're using. Plus when you move the mulch (if it hasn't biodegraded too quickly) you'll be disrupting any mycorrhizal strands when you do

Comment: soil, umm . . . I mean fungal walkways so I can walk on fungi. The city forces tillage on everyone, so I want to promote fungi back in my plot.

Comment: Wait!  I gotta know what you mean about the city forces tillage?  Tillage does not destroy life in the soil unless that soil gets drained of life, like no food, no decomposed organic matter...and tilled annually.  Tilling one time does not kill life in the soil, it enhances life.  Mainly because most life you want to promote is aerobic.  Under duress, fungi goes dormant only to come back with a vengeance when conditions are better.  What are these plant sugars?

Comment: Tilling does not damage the fauna and fungi in the soil. They probably don't know whats happening but they love the air and mobility and all the different racial stuff...there is too much tilling and that is out there.  Not in residential land though.  I think you want to make double duty out of your walkways?  I leave my walkways alone, allow them to become compacted.  Heck, I have never ever ever had any problems with weeds in my walkways, or my plant beds for that matter. What are these plant sugars?  I certainly hope you provide proper 'dinner attire' for these oh so lucky fungi...grins!

Comment: Well, interesting - someone's downvoted my answer - since when did pointing out the question isn't clear warrant a downvote may I ask? Not that the vote matters, its the principle of the thing...

Comment: @Bamboo It doesn't clarification is the key so you asking for it when you are confused is not only necessary but should be encouraged.